# httprequest exception handling php

Tags: php, http, exception

In case a request cannot be made, how can I catch the exception?

I have so far written this, but not had any luck.

```
$url = 'http://localhost:49000/';
//create the httprequest object                
try{
  $httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST, $options);
}catch(HttpException $e){
  echo $e;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How do you mean you haven't had any luck? It looks like valid exception handling.

Comment: You should enable PHP errors: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: In your php.ini, do you have error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = On? You should get more information than "Internal Server error 500".

Comment: error_reporting(0); I have this enabled in my controller

Comment: error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
Just checked my php.ini file error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
 this is uncommented.

Comment: error_reporting(0) quashes all errors. Remove that from your controller. You should use the constant names for clarity, but in any case, you can see what their numerical values are here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you should make sure that the exception is in the namespace.

What I've done is:

```
try {
    //Request here
} catch (\HttpException $e) {
    //Handle exception
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //Just in case
}
```

Also good to notice what is pointed in this article http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/06/how-to-pecl-http-request-exception-and-error-handling/ about the inner exception, in case you want the message returned by the exception.

Also, there is a php.ini directive that forces HttpRequest to always throw exception http://br.php.net/manual/en/http.configuration.php http.only_exceptions=1

Answer (score 0):

> how can I catch the exception?

To catch an exception you need to know the classname of the exception. What is the classname of the exception you'd like to catch?